# ¿Como capturar el 'name' de una descripción? [UWP] [C#]

Tags: c#, uwp, string

Buenas es que tengo esta propiedad

```
[Display(Name = "Codigo EAN-UCC", Description = "Codigo EAN-UCC para recaudos por codigo de barras", GroupName = "Tesoreria")] 
public string TESORERIA_CODEANUCC 
{ get { return (Get() == null ? "" : (string)Get()); } set { Set(value); RaisePropertyChanged(); } }
```

¿Como puedo capturar las etiquetas 'Description', 'GroupName', o 'Name' para guardarlar en un campo o mostrarlas en pantalla en un mensaje?, es mas de pronto hasta mas adelante tenga que modificarlas

No se si la pregunta esta bien formulada, acepto modificaciones

Comment: sino defines  {get; set;} no es ninguna propiedad

Comment: ya lo edito....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es simple pero podrias usar `Reflection` para acceder a los atributos de la propiedad

[Using Custom Attributes in C# - By David Clegg](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30250)

veras que primero obtiene las propiedades que quizas podrias filtrar usando linq si fuera necesario

```
MemberInfo[] members = classType.GetMembers();
```

para despues obtener los atributos

```
object[] attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

por lo que podrias iteral y acceder a su valor

```
foreach (object attribute in attributes) {
    DisplayAttribute attr = attribute as DisplayAttribute;
        if (attr != null)
           //aqui accedes a attr.Description 
}
```

quizas deberias armar otro objeto para ir volcando los datos que luego uses para bindear en xaml